# Differences between NCQRS and Lokad.CQRS

Tags: azure, cloud, cqrs, lokad-cqrs

I am currently looking at [CQRS](http://blog.fossmo.net/post/Command-and-Query-Responsibility-Segregation-%28CQRS%29.aspx) frameworks to use for a project that will be hosted in [Azure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_Services_Platform).

I have read about [Ncqrs](http://ncqrs.org/) and Lokad.CQRS and am currently a little bit confused.

Will they both work with Azure, are both capable of using NServiceBus or does Lokad use its own messaging?

The clients I will use are both web and mobile. I thought of making a WCF service to get commands, but not sure it will be WCF.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lokad.CQRS was designed to work with Azure from the start. It uses Azure Queues for the  messaging (with azure blobs for the cases, when messages do not fit in 8Kb size limitation).

I'm not sure about NCqrs, but it might provide an adapter for Lokad.CQRS.

Comment: Great. what about NServiceBus is that integrated with Lokad.CQRS or? I will try to use Lokad.CQRS for at booking project and the framework really looks great

Comment: At the moment I have an ASPNET MVC project used as an API, is it possible to keep that (changed later) and then from this send messages with Lokad.CQRS? and ofcourse in Azure.

Comment: Rasmus, NServiceBus is a separate project, and I don't plan to integrate it directly with Lokad.CQRS. However, sending messages between these two might be possible.

Comment: 2. It is possible to send commands and query views from ASP.NET MVC application (hosted in Azure or outside). That's how we actually do at Lokad for the web and desktop clients.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will look into it all as soon as I can

Comment: Rasmus, a quick comment. Lokad.CQRSv2 will be released as beta next week. Current version is a bit outdated.